# Infinite loop in component will update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop

When my code is ran it continuously loops through `ComponentDidUpdate()`. So my question is what lifecycle method should I use then? Because it is looping through that since my component is calling it repeatedly in `Render` right? Or is that an incorrect assumption? I tried `ComponentWillMount()` but that is rendering an empty array everytime.

**Component**

```
 const NetflixTile = ({ videos }) => {
      console.log("In tile " + JSON.stringify(videos));
      if (videos.length != 0) {
        for (let i = 0; videos.length > i; i++) {
          console.log();

          return (
            <div className="row__inner">
              <div className="tile">
                <div className="tile__media">
                  <img
                    className="tile__img"
                    id="thumbnail"
                    src="this.state.penis"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      } else {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>
              You have not yet uploaded any STEM content. Go to your dashboard page
              and click Upload to add to this library.
            </h1>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };

    export default NetflixTile;
```

### **Render Class**

**Constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.getVideos();
    this.state = {
      thumbnail: []
    };
  }
```

**Render snippet**

```
  return (
      <div className="explore">
        <div className="row">
          <NetflixTile videos={this.state.thumbnail} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

**ComponentDidUpdate**

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    console.log("Current State->" + this.state.thumbnail);
    console.log("Previous State->" + prevState.thumbnail);

    if (this.props.videos == null) {
      console.log("It's null");
    } else {
      if (this.state !== prevState) {
        const videos = this.props.videos.video.map(video => {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            thumbnail: [...prevState.thumbnail, video.thumbnail]
          }));
          console.log(this.state.thumbnail);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Edit**
I changed componentDidUpdate as suggested, but cannot figure out why `this.state.thumbnail` is returning with not even an array. `prevState.thumbnail` is just undefined. If I do just `prevState` it does return the object though.

[image]

Comment: Calling `this.setState()` will always cause an update. You can use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` to determine whether or not to actually update.

Answer (score 2):

React documentation says:

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs.
> This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component
> has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as
> long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a
> network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

This is important for you:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note
> that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or
> you’ll cause an infinite loop.

You must not use the setstate without condition, setting state in componentDidUpdate will cause the infinite loop.

I would say completely avoid them.

**Which method to use?**

If you are using previous version then 16.3 use `componentWillReceiveProps`
If you are using 16.3 or above then use `getDerivedStateFromProps`

[Here is an interesting conversation to read](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#updating-state-based-on-props)

**Update as per comment:**

You need to be specific when applying the condition, this.state !== prevState` is not enough.

Let say you have this.state.counter = 1 and you are updating the into `componentDidUpdate` and incrementing this.state.counter as 2.

This will always results into infinite loop.

Comment: I tried using conditions for componentDidUpdate() and posted my updated code and console output.

Comment: I get it, but when I use prevState.thumbnail it returns undefined. Because that makes complete sense of having to go into the next "level" of state.

Comment: Yes, the first time it will return undefined but the nextime you should receive the state changed, `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` here is the defination of it. I doubt you are having prevProps instead of state.